# Python : stripping, converting bytes type

Tags: python-3.x

Under Python 3.10, I do have an UDP socket that listens to a COM port.
I do get datas like this :

```
b'SENDPKT: "STN1" "" "SH/DX\r"\x98\x00'
```

The infos SH/DX before the "\n" can change and has a different length and I need to extract them.

*.strip('b\r') doesn't work.*

Using *.decode()* and *str()*, I tried to convert this bytes datas to a string for easier manipulation, but that doesn't work either.
I get an error "invalid start byte at position 27 for 0x98

Any guess, how I can solve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: what part exactly need to be extracted `SENDPKT: "STN1" "" "SH/DX` ?

Comment: in this case, it is SH/DX, but it can be SH/WWW or something else. I can extract it with data[19:23] but I would like data[19:], so I need the strip() the end after \n

Comment: there's `\r`, not `\n`

Comment: You corrected it. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sophisticated input you can try ignoring errors while decoding:

```
b = b'SENDPKT: "STN1" "" "SH/DX\r"\x98\x00'
s = b.decode(errors='ignore')
res = s[20:s.find('\r')]   # 'SH/DX'
```

Comment: Long live Ukraine !